# AWS Lambda questions

Tags: api, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I am using AWS Lambda as a backend - however I cannot figure out how to interact with my SQL database on Amazon RDS.

I would simply like to be able to write API function inLambda to access and retrieve information from the database.

To do this in python i would normally use the 'MySQLdb' module - however Lambda does not have this.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you you want to use external libraries, you need to create a deployment package that contains them and upload it via AWS console or S3.

More information here:
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/lambda-python-how-to-create-deployment-package.html

Comment: After several attempts to do so I am having no luck. Is it possible to simple upload the module and then use than within the console editor in lambda>?

Comment: Try the following workaround:
Open .py file for your module and copy the code of all necessary functions directly to the body of your lambda function. But it could be chalanging if it has a lot of dependences.

Comment: I have to install jwplatform module in AWS Lambda using Python but did not get success yet. I have locally install jwplatform and create deployment package and upload zip in AWS Lambda but it gives errorMessage :"Unable to import module 'lambda_function'" .Anyone please help me

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 options.

**Option 1**

Like Vladimir mentioned, you have to package `MySQLdb` module along with your Lambda code and import `MySQLdb` in your Lambda code.

**Option 2**

Use Boto3 [RDS](http://boto3.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/services/rds.html) module which is included in Lambda/Python. No need to package anything extra. Just import `boto3`. One drawback is you have rewrite your code using boto3 instead `MySQLdb`