# how to write my AWS lambda function?

Tags: python, python-2.7, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, boto3

I am new to AWS lambda function and i am trying to add my existing code to AWS lambda. My existing code looks like :

```
import boto3
import slack
import slack.chat
import time
import itertools
from slacker import Slacker

ACCESS_KEY = ""
SECRET_KEY = ""
slack.api_token = ""
slack_channel = "#my_test_channel"

def gather_info_ansible():
           .
           .

def call_snapshot_creater(data):
           .
           . 
def call_snapshot_destroyer(data):
           .
           .
if __name__ == '__main__':
    print "Calling Ansible Box Gather detail Method first!"
    ansible_box_info = gather_info_ansible()

    print "Now Calling the Destroyer of SNAPSHOT!! BEHOLD THIS IS HELL!!"
    call_snapshot_destroyer(ansible_box_info)

    #mapping = {i[0]: [i[1], i[2]] for i in data}
    print "Now Calling the Snapshot Creater!"
    call_snapshot_creater(ansible_box_info)
```

Now i try to create a lambda function from scratch on AWS Console as follows (a hello world)

```
from __future__ import print_function

import json


print('Loading function')


def lambda_handler(event, context):
    #print("Received event: " + json.dumps(event, indent=2))
    print("value1 = " + event['key1'])
    print("value2 = " + event['key2'])
    print("value3 = " + event['key3'])
    print("test")
    return event['key1']  # Echo back the first key value
    #raise Exception('Something went wrong')
```

and the sample test event on AWS console is :

```
{
  "key3": "value3",
  "key2": "value2",
  "key1": "value1"
}
```

I am really not sure how to put my code in AWS lambda coz if i even add the modules in lambda console and run it it throws me error :

```
Unable to import module 'lambda_function': No module named slack
```

How to solve this and import my code in lambda?

Answer (score 3):

You have to make a zipped package consisting of your python script containing the lambda function and all the modules that you are importing in the python script. Upload the zipped package on aws.

Whatever module you want to import, you have to include that module in the zip package. Only then the import statements will work.

For example your zip package should consist of

```
test_package.zip
|-test.py (script containing the lambda_handler function)
|-boto3(module folder)
|-slack(module folder)
|-slacker(module folder)
```

Comment: what/how exactly i will put inside the lambda function ? i mean should i simply call the other methods from inside the lambda_handler ?

Comment: @Yusuf , please tell me also what should be the structure of my test.py ? I mean do i call my other methods from inside of lambda_handler function "?

Comment: If you want to import other modules then you have to upload a package. You will not be able to import the modules by creating a lambda function from the console. Make a zip package of 1. python script containing lambda handler function where you will be importing all the modules and 2. All the modules that you are importing in the python script.

Comment: yes you are right you should call all your methods from within the lambda_handler function.

Comment: i tried uploading the package and i am not sure it gets uploaded even ,.. i get the `  "errorMessage": "Unable to import module 'lambda_function'"`

Comment: When you fill the Handler function text box on configure function page, change the Handler name to your_python_script_name.lambda_handler

Comment: basically in the handler function text box you have to write your_python_script_name.your_lambda_handler_function_name_inside_your_python_script. So its not necessary that you name your lambda function as lambda_handler(). You can name it as you like and enter that name in the Handler function text box.

Comment: So the handler will be: `test.lambda_handler`, right? But i still get error:  `"errorMessage": "Unable to import module 'test'"`

Comment: @BMW `def lambda_handler(event, context):` will be a function inside `test.py`. It will be a point of entry for all requests. Check this: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/python-programming-model-handler-types.html

Comment: Thanks, @MYGz I spend several hours, but still can't get it work. I have a simple python code copied from the lambda template directly, which has `def lambda_handler(event, context)`, file name is `test.py`. I add a new module `requests`,  then zip and upload. But still have the error. The error is about not find module `test`, not `lambda_handler`

Comment: ok, i fix the problem, because i use linux zip command to archive it. Seems it doesn't work with it. I have to find a windows sytem, use winzip, then everything works fine.  AWS doesn't mention this in anywhere.

Answer (score 1):

You receive an error because AWS lambda does not have any information about a module called slack.

A module is a set of .py files that are stored somewhere on a computer.
In case of lambda, you should import all your libraries by creating a deployment package.

Here is an another question that describes similar case and provides several solutions:
[AWS Lambda questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35479897/aws-lambda-questions)

Comment: oh okay.. so basically i should extrat the modules from the installed directory and then create a deployment package in zip format ? 

also i am not clear what to write inside the lambda function ?